How to do svg laser pointer in js. like one in excalidraw or google slides?
I trying to create a mouse trail using svg path elements.
used beziers for smoothening but somehow smoothening is not good.
can some one help me with this.


const smoothing = 0.10;

function line(pointA, pointB) {
  // Calculate the horizontal distance between pointA and pointB
  var lengthX = pointB[0] - pointA[0];
  // Calculate the vertical distance between pointA and pointB
  var lengthY = pointB[1] - pointA[1];

  // Calculate the length of the line segment using Pythagoras theorem
  var length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lengthX, 2) + Math.pow(lengthY, 2));



  // Calculate the angle of the line segment relative to the x-axis
  var angle = Math.atan2(lengthY, lengthX);

  // Return an object containing the length and angle of the line segment
  return {
    length: length,
    angle: angle
  };
}



function controlPoint(current, previous, next, reverse) {
  // Use previous point as fallback if it doesn't exist
  var p = previous || current;
  // Use next point as fallback if it doesn't exist
  var n = next || current;

  // Calculate the line between previous and next points
  var o = line(p, n);

  // Calculate angle based on line's angle and whether to reverse
  var angle = o.angle + (reverse ? Math.PI : 0);
  // Calculate length with smoothing factor
  var length = o.length * smoothing;

  // Calculate new control point coordinates
  var x = current[0] + Math.cos(angle) * length;
  var y = current[1] + Math.sin(angle) * length;

  return [x, y]; // Return the control point coordinates
}


function bezierCommand(point, i, points) {
  // Get the control points
  var cps = controlPoint(points[i - 1], points[i - 2], point);
  var cpe = controlPoint(point, points[i - 1], points[i + 1], true);

  // Construct and return the Bezier command string
  var command = "C " + cps[0] + "," + cps[1] + " " + cpe[0] + "," + cpe[1] + " " + point[0] + "," + point[1];
  return command;
}



function svgPath(points, command) {
  // Initialize the 'd' attribute string
  var d = "";

  // Loop over the points
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var point = points[i];

    // If it's the first point, start with 'M'
    if (i === 0) {
      d += "M " + point[0] + "," + point[1];
    } else {
      // Otherwise, append the command for the current point
      d += " " + command(point, i, points);
    }
  }

  // Return the SVG path string
  return '<path d="' + d + '" fill="none" stroke="red" class="paths"/>';
}

var lastMousePoints = [];
const svg = document.querySelector('#mouse-trail')


function addPoint(x, y) {
  lastMousePoints.push([x, y]);
  if (lastMousePoints.length > 20) {
    lastMousePoints.shift();
    svg.innerHTML = svgPath(lastMousePoints, bezierCommand)
  } else if (lastMousePoints.length === 2) {
    svg.innerHTML = svgPath(lastMousePoints, bezierCommand)
  } else if (lastMousePoints.length > 2) {
    svg.innerHTML = svgPath(lastMousePoints, bezierCommand)

  }
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  addPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY);
});
.paths {
  stroke-width: 1.5;
}
<svg id="mouse-trail" width="100%" height="100vh"></svg>



I'm storing the last 20 points of mouse and creating the path with the coordinates.
any other approaches are welcome too.
Note : should not use external libraries for this, I'm trying to create laser pointer effect like the one in excalidraw and google slides.

You may adapt some line smoothing concepts as explained here "SVG smooth freehand drawing"

You can adapt @ConnorsFan's polyline smoothing concept from this answer
SVG smooth freehand drawing.
Basically you're collecting multiple mouse input coordinates in a buffer. The drawn polyline is based on averaged coordinates – this will smooth jitters in the original point array.
Bigger buffer sizes will increase smoothing but also add an input lag.
I highly recommend to convert screen to SVG coordinates. Otherwise you may encounter problems when the SVG's viewBox size don't match the rendered layout size.


let svg = document.querySelector("#mouse-trail");

// collect coordinates
let lastMousePoints = [];
let maxVertices = 32;

// create buffer for polyline smoothing
let buffer = [];
let bufferSize = 8;


svg.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  addPoint(e);
});

function addPoint(e) {

  // get point in svg coordinate system
  let pt = getMouseOrTouchPos(svg, e);

  // append to buffer for smoothing
  buffer.push(pt);

  // start with lower buffer length if buffer not filled
  if (buffer.length < bufferSize && buffer.length > 4) {
    // get smoothed coordinates
    pt = getAveragePoint(buffer, 4);
    lastMousePoints.push(pt);
  }


  if (buffer.length > bufferSize) {

    // get smoothed coordinates
    pt = getAveragePoint(buffer, bufferSize);
    lastMousePoints.push(pt);

    // reset buffer
    buffer.shift();
  }


  // remove points
  if (lastMousePoints.length > maxVertices) {
    lastMousePoints.shift();
  }

  // update polyline
  polyline.setAttribute(
    "points",
    lastMousePoints
    .map((pt) => {
      return [pt.x, pt.y].join(' ');
    })
    .join(" ")
  );

}

/**
 * based on @ConnorsFan's answer
 * SVG smooth freehand drawing
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324313/svg-smooth-freehand-drawing/#40700068
 */
// Calculate the average point, starting at offset in the buffer
function getAveragePoint(buffer, bufferSize) {
  var len = buffer.length;
  let offset = Math.floor(len / 4);
  offset = len > 8 ? len - 2 : 0
  offset = 0;
  if (len % 2 === 1 || len >= bufferSize) {
    var totalX = 0;
    var totalY = 0;
    var pt, i;
    var count = 0;
    for (i = offset; i < len; i++) {
      count++;
      pt = buffer[i];
      totalX += pt.x;
      totalY += pt.y;
    }
    return {
      x: totalX / count,
      y: totalY / count
    };
  }
  return null;
}

/**
 * based on:
 * @Daniel Lavedonio de Lima
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/61732450/3355076
 */
function getMouseOrTouchPos(svg, e) {
  let x, y;
  // touch cooordinates
  if (
    e.type == "touchstart" ||
    e.type == "touchmove" ||
    e.type == "touchend" ||
    e.type == "touchcancel"
  ) {
    let evt = typeof e.originalEvent === "undefined" ? e : e.originalEvent;
    let touch = evt.touches[0] || evt.changedTouches[0];
    x = touch.pageX;
    y = touch.pageY;
  } else if (
    e.type == "mousedown" ||
    e.type == "mouseup" ||
    e.type == "mousemove" ||
    e.type == "mouseover" ||
    e.type == "mouseout" ||
    e.type == "mouseenter" ||
    e.type == "mouseleave"
  ) {
    x = e.clientX;
    y = e.clientY;
  }

  // get svg user space coordinates
  let point = new DOMPoint(x, y);
  let ctm = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();
  point = point.matrixTransform(ctm);
  return {
    x: point.x,
    y: point.y
  };
}
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

polyline {
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: red;
  fill: none;
}
<svg id="mouse-trail" width="100%" height="100vh">
  <polyline id="polyline" pathLength="100" />
    </svg>



